cargo build -j 2 command gives error
I am trying to build a solana project
Specifications
rustc --version
rustc 1.83.0 (90b35a623 2024-11-26)
solana --version
solana-cli 2.0.18 (src:f77014dc; feat:607245837, client:Agave)
anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.30.1
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:
warning: blake3@1.5.1: In file included from c/blake3_neon.c:1:
warning: blake3@1.5.1: c/blake3_impl.h:4:10: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found
warning: blake3@1.5.1:     4 | #include <assert.h>
warning: blake3@1.5.1:       |          ^~~~~~~~~~
warning: blake3@1.5.1: 1 error generated.

error: failed to run custom build command for `blake3 v1.5.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/abhishekkumar/Documents/EddyV3/vote_new_gov/anchor/target/debug/build/blake3-039bece89673e29b/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_PURE
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_NO_NEON
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_NEON
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_NEON
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_NO_NEON
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_PURE
  cargo:rustc-cfg=blake3_neon
  OUT_DIR = Some(/Users/abhishekkumar/Documents/EddyV3/vote_new_gov/anchor/target/debug/build/blake3-4f64dab5f40853db/out)
  TARGET = Some(aarch64-apple-darwin)
  OPT_LEVEL = Some(0)
  HOST = Some(aarch64-apple-darwin)
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_aarch64-apple-darwin
  CC_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_aarch64_apple_darwin
  CC_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT
  RUSTC_WRAPPER = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some(true)
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
  MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin
  CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin
  CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:warning=In file included from c/blake3_neon.c:1:
  cargo:warning=c/blake3_impl.h:4:10: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found
  cargo:warning=    4 | #include <assert.h>
  cargo:warning=      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=1 error generated.

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command env -u IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-gdwarf-2" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "--target=arm64-apple-darwin" "-mmacosx-version-min=15.1" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c11" "-o" "/Users/abhishekkumar/Documents/EddyV3/vote_new_gov/anchor/target/debug/build/blake3-4f64dab5f40853db/out/db3b6bfb95261072-blake3_neon.o" "-c" "c/blake3_neon.c" with args cc did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1).


warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
(base) ➜  anchor git:(main) ✗ 


If assert.h isn't found on your system, you might need to install libc
